# Proguard error on APP release - android/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

Proguard failed with this message after optimizing app.

compileSdkVersion = 27

buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"

minSdkVersion = 16

targetSdkVersion = 27

`Shrinking...
Removing unused program classes and class elements...
  Original number of program classes: 6833
  Final number of program classes:    6348
Optimizing...
Unexpected error while computing stack sizes:
  Class       = [android/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$1]
  Method      = [zzf(Ljava/lang/String;)J]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Stack size becomes negative after instruction [24] invokestatic #4625 in [android/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$1.zzf(Ljava/lang/String;)J])
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stack size becomes negative after instruction [24] invokestatic #4625 in [android/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$1.zzf(Ljava/lang/String;)J]
Thread(Tasks limiter_5): destruction
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I fixed this by commenting these lines in proguard file:

```
#-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
#    public static *** d(...);
#    public static *** v(...);
#    public static *** i(...);
#    public static *** w(...);
#    public static *** e(...);
```

I ended up using if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) for each log